# Urm, List<T>() in C++/CX? Any kind of List, Collection - even an ObvervableCollection?

Tags: visual-c++, windows-runtime, c++-cx

I am trying to bind (in XAML) to a List in C++/CX and I can't seem to have any Lists. Where'd they all go? Any kind of list will do... Even a Dictionary, or Stack, or ... something! Or has C++ changed *that much* since I last used it?

Comment: If you're using C++/CLI, you will find all the collections in `System.Collections.Generic`. You can't bind to native C++ collections.

Comment: No idea about what the question is...

Comment: -1 btw what's 'C++/CLI' @R.MartinhoFernandes ?

Comment: I already tried System.Collections.Generic. There's nothing there.

Comment: @Walter Oh, it's the .NET C++ thingy. I keep forgetting there's also that new Metro thingy, C++/CX. I honestly hope people won't regularly confuse C++11 with C++/CX.

Comment: Metro is what I'm making the app for. So, if you can't bind native collections, how would I bind list of files in a directory?

Comment: The question seems very clear to me. I am disappointed at the dismissive attitude of other commenters. There is absolutely no point in stating that you don't know what C++/CLI is, either; if you don't understand a technical term in a question, don't comment on it, or look it up. The question is useful, and airs a commonly found difficulty: that while the standard C++ library, and the .NET library used with C++/CLI, both have list classes, C++/CX, used for developing on Windows Phone, etc., does not. This problem always has to be solved when porting a C++ library between these platforms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are C++/CX implementations of the Windows collection interfaces in the [`Platform::Collections`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh710418.aspx) namespace, defined in `<collection.h>`.

See also the article on [Collections in C++/CX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700103.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Thanks @James. I also found this to be pretty helpful, too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh758320.aspx